# ViewPager how to preload next view Android

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I want to be able to preload next `ViewPager` page with dynamic content on android. I add content to view, after view has been created.

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_layout, null);
    view.setTag("rel" + position);
    collection.addView(view, 0);
    return view;
}
```

if I try to get next view, with `findViewWithTag("rel" + (view1.getCurrentItem() + 1));` it returns `null`. So, how could I get next view, or inflate it manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `setOffscreenPageLimit(int limit)` method of `ViewPager` class.

Comment: Thanks, that was it

Answer (score 0):

getItem method is called before going to next position so you can pass whatever dynamic data u want in getInstance

private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

```
    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
        switch(pos) {

        case 0: return FirstFragment.newInstance("FirstFragment, Instance 1");
        case 1: return SecondFragment.newInstance("SecondFragment, Instance 1");
        case 2: return ThirdFragment.newInstance("ThirdFragment, Instance 1");
        case 3: return ThirdFragment.newInstance("ThirdFragment, Instance 2");
        case 4: return ThirdFragment.newInstance("ThirdFragment, Instance 3");
        default: return ThirdFragment.newInstance("ThirdFragment, Default");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }       
}
```

public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_frag, container, false);

    TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvFragFirst);
    tv.setText(getArguments().getString("msg"));

    return v;
}

public static FirstFragment newInstance(String text) {

    FirstFragment f = new FirstFragment();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("msg", text);

    f.setArguments(b);

    return f;
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I reuse same layout in activity with view pager and I just fill it with different content, I do not use fragments at the moment. Also I have 30 pages, so instantiating all of them could lead to out of memory JVM, I add bitmaps to layouts